# Rpi4 Video camera driver not loaded on Ubuntu 19.10 server 64bit

Tags: drivers, video, camera

I have been testing Ubuntu 19.10 server 64bit on Rpi4 with 4 gig ram. Making some progress but I am stuck trying to use the Rpi camera with OpenCV. Works with Raspbian OS.

Trying to load video driver with the following.

- lsmod | sort
- displays bmc2835_v4l2
- add it to /etc/modules
- sudo vim /etc/modules
- save and reboot.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Regards
Steve

Comment: Oops, forgot to check permission for group video on /dev/video0.

Comment: Looking at this issue right now. modprobe: FATAL: Module bmc2835_v4l2 not found in directory /lib/modules/5.3.0-1012-raspi2

Comment: Adding  
start_x=1 
gpu_mem=128
to
/boot/firmware/config.txt
and reboot allows me to see /dev/video0.

Comment: Nice! working now on 19.10 server 64 bit. Have to write it up and share when I get a little more time to play with it.

Comment: I did all you've described but can't get it to work, loaded the module and added the configuration options. What else did you do or install?